# Subir imagen CkeditorJS en Django

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor

Saludos tengo implementado Ckeditor Versión 4, el documento sube efectivamente,
le problema surgue en retornar la respuesta, la misma que nose como debe ser el esquema para que automaticamente se coloque la url retornada de la imagen previamente subida tal como lo hace el mismo editor :

[Demo subir imagen Ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/fileupload.html#uploading-dropped-and-pasted-images)

La funcion que recibe mi editor de texto en Django es:

```
@csrf_exempt
def SubirImagenCkeditor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
        myfile = request.FILES['upload']
        CKEditorFuncNum = request.GET['CKEditorFuncNum']
        langCode = request.GET['langCode']
        CKEditor = request.GET['CKEditor']
        message = ''
        print CKEditorFuncNum
        print langCode
        print CKEditor
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location='media/sacs')
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = 'media/sacs/' + filename
        data = {
            'fileName':filename,
            'uploaded':1,
            'url':uploaded_file_url
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Dicha funcion la cumple correctamente, incluso retorna el Json pero no me copia automaticamente la url a donde deberia como muestra el demo en CKEDITOR, de esta manera me retorna mi respuesta Json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tal como se ve en la imagen me muestra mi respuesta, pero no copia la url automaticamente en donde deberia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tambien he visto como deberia retornar en PHP, intente lo mismo en Python pero sin resultado de esta manera deberia retornar en php:

```
<?php
// Upload script for CKEditor.
// Use at your own risk, no warranty provided. Be careful about who is able to access this file
// The upload folder shouldn't be able to upload any kind of script, just in case.
// If you're not sure, hire a professional that takes care of adjusting the server configuration as well as this script for you.
// (I am not such professional)
// Step 1: change the true for whatever condition you use in your environment to verify that the user
// is logged in and is allowed to use the script
if ( true ) {
    echo("You're not allowed to upload files");
    die(0);
}
// Step 2: Put here the full absolute path of the folder where you want to save the files:
// You must set the proper permissions on that folder (I think that it's 644, but don't trust me on this one)
// ALWAYS put the final slash (/)
$basePath = "/home/user/example.com/files/";
// Step 3: Put here the Url that should be used for the upload folder (it the URL to access the folder that you have set in $basePath
// you can use a relative url "/images/", or a path including the host "http://example.com/images/"
// ALWAYS put the final slash (/)
$baseUrl = "/files/";
// Done. Now test it!
// No need to modify anything below this line
//----------------------------------------------------
// ------------------------
// Input parameters: optional means that you can ignore it, and required means that you
// must use it to provide the data back to CKEditor.
// ------------------------
// Optional: instance name (might be used to adjust the server folders for example)
$CKEditor = $_GET['CKEditor'] ;
// Required: Function number as indicated by CKEditor.
$funcNum = $_GET['CKEditorFuncNum'] ;
// Optional: To provide localized messages
$langCode = $_GET['langCode'] ;
// ------------------------
// Data processing
// ------------------------
// The returned url of the uploaded file
$url = '' ;
// Optional message to show to the user (file renamed, invalid file, not authenticated...)
$message = '';
// in CKEditor the file is sent as 'upload'
if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
    // Be careful about all the data that it's sent!!!
    // Check that the user is authenticated, that the file isn't too big,
    // that it matches the kind of allowed resources...
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    // It doesn't care if the file already exists, it's simply overwritten.
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $basePath . $name);
    // Build the url that should be used for this file   
    $url = $baseUrl . $name ;
    // Usually you don't need any message when everything is OK.
//    $message = 'new file uploaded';   
}
else
{
    $message = 'No file has been sent';
}
// ------------------------
// Write output
// ------------------------
// We are in an iframe, so we must talk to the object in window.parent
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message')</script>";
?>
```

Agradecercia cualquier sugerencia o ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos si a alguien le sirve dejare la solución hallada:

```
@csrf_exempt
def SubirImagenCkeditor(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
        PATH_IMAGENES_SAC = "media/recursosSac/"
        #archivo
        myfile = request.FILES['upload']
        #parametros CKEDITOR
        CKEditorFuncNum = request.GET['CKEditorFuncNum']
        langCode = request.GET['langCode']
        CKEditor = request.GET['CKEditor']
        #SUBIR DOCUMENTO
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location=PATH_IMAGENES_SAC)
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = PATH_IMAGENES_SAC + filename

        #VALIDAR EXTENSION
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(uploaded_file_url)
        if file_extension == '.jpg' or file_extension =='.png':
            message = ''
            URL_IMAGEN = "'"+uploaded_file_url+"'"
            HTML_CODIGO ="<script type='text/javascript'> window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("+CKEditorFuncNum+","+URL_IMAGEN+", 'Archivo subido !!')</script>"
            return HttpResponse(HTML_CODIGO)
        else:
            os.remove(uploaded_file_url)
            HTML_CODIGO = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Extensión no permitida !!');</script>"
            return HttpResponse(HTML_CODIGO)
    else:
        MENSAJE= "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('error - No se ha subido la imagen !!');</script>"
        return HttpResponse(MENSAJE)
```

Lo que hice fue armar la respuesta como una cadena(string) la misma es mandada por HttpResponse hacia la funcion que la invocay listo funciono perfecto, espero les sirva..!!